# MySQL Stored procedure fails to produce reults

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

```
mysql> select * from S_TABLE;
+--------+--------------------+
|   S_ID | S_TITLE            |
+--------+--------------------+
|      1 |  Jim               |
|      2 |  George            |
|      3 |  Sam               |
|      4 |  Zoe               |
+--------+--------------------+

mysql> select * from F_TABLE;
+--------+--------+--------------+----------+
| F_ID   |  S_ID  | F_VALUE      | F_TITLE  |
+--------+--------+--------------+----------+
|      1 |      1 | 4.5          | Delta    |
|      2 |      2 | 24.5         | Gamma    |
|      3 |      3 | 44.4         | RHO      |
|      4 |      3 | 5.0          | Beta     |
+--------+--------+--------------+----------+

mysql> select * from Results; // Hence this table is empty
+--------+-------------+
| Fstuff | Sstuff      |
+--------+-------------+
|        |             |
+--------+-------------+
```

**`This stored procedure does a frivolous computation`**

```
DELIMITER ##
CREATE PROCEDURE zap(IN sss VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO Results (fstuff, Sstuff)
Select 
f.F_VALUE * 0 + 123,
s.S_TITLE
FROM F_TABLE f
JOIN S_TABLE s ON s.S_ID=f.S_ID
WHERE s.S_TITLE LIKE CONCAT('%', sss, '%');

END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

**`This stored procedure calls zap`**

```
DELIMITER ##
CREATE PROCEDURE crap()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fTit VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT F_TITLE FROM F_TABLE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP

        FETCH cur INTO fTit;

        IF done 
            THEN LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        call Zap(fTit);
        COMMIT;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;

END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

**Problem: Result table becomes uneffected? I cant figure out why**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read out the names from `F_TABLE.F_TITLE` (Delta,Gamma...) and look for them in `S_TABLE.S_TITLE` and there is no match.

The cursor in `crap` should use the same title column as the `zap` procedure.

edit:

The cursor `cur CURSOR FOR SELECT F_TITLE FROM F_TABLE;` will fetch 'Delta','Gamma' and so on into `fTit`. Then `Zap()` is called: 
`Zap('Delta')`, `Zap('Gamma')` etc.

The `Zap` procedure will create a match string `'%Delta%'`, `'%Gamma%'` and so on and look for this in the first table you listed. Since that table contains 'Jim', 'George' and other names there is no match. The `SELECT` returns no rows so there is nothing inserted in any of the calls to `zap`.

If you change the cursor to instead look in `S_TABLE` you will get rows inserted, but maybe not the ones you want. Please explain more what you expect in the results table.

Comment: Can you further explain/exemplify that?

Comment: \ EKman Desired result is to have the Result table populated with every F_TITLE & F_VALUE from the F_TABLE with its valued changed to 123.

Comment: Change contents of `zap` to `INSERT INTO Results (fstuff, Sstuff)
    Select 
    123,
    s.S_TITLE
    FROM F_TABLE f
    JOIN S_TABLE s ON s.S_ID=f.S_ID
    WHERE f.F_TITLE LIKE CONCAT('%', sss, '%');`

Answer (score 1):

I can't spot any syntax errors in the procedures' logic.

But this condition:

```
WHERE s.S_TITLE LIKE CONCAT('%', sss, '%')
```

seems to be false for all combinations of the two sample tables (the `sss` gets values form the `F_TABLE.F_TITLE` column). This means that no rows will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Is autocommit set or perhaps you need `COMMIT`, at the end of `crap`.

Comment: I'm a newb so Im not sure what commit does. Where would I do a 'commit' ? And what does that do to the Stored procedure?

Comment: Don't you need a 'GO' or something?

Comment: @Stevo which line? which stored procedure?

Comment: @Stevo: `GO` is SQL Server specific, and used for batching statements -- not committing.

Comment: @OMGPonies zap works good on its own and produces results in the result table. But when I try to call it from crap it doesn't work.

Comment: `DECLARE fTit VARCHAR(45);`should the 45 be 30?

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: Sorry, everyone's covered what sticks out to me.

Comment: @Ed Heal 45 and it matches the table's size too if that was your after

Comment: @OMGPonies you helped me several times before. I'm eager to hear what you think is the cause

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: I'm flattered, but I don't have anything this time.  Sorry :(

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it - zap takes 30, change zap to 45 then?

Comment: @Ed Heal, I just did that and still nothing

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: (after your edit) the `zap()` procedure has one parameter but it is called with 2.

Comment: @ypercube I'm trying to eliminate all ambiguity from anyone trying to help me so I delimited to one arg. Thanks for pointing out that I forgot to amend the procedure ( i fixed it)